# A simple question.Is there a way to load css link with jquery dynamic?In $.ajax or something else?

Tags: css, ajax, dynamic, jquery

I can use jquery  load lots of  thing with ajax ,like script,html,xml,json

But I wonder is it possible to load or remove css file or link with jquery ?When I want change website's theme.

If it is possible ,could any body tell how to do it exactly?Or is there a tutorial?

Thank you:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's fairly straightforward once you know how.

```
$('head').append('<link rel="stylsheet" href="my-style.css" />');
```

Or:

```
$('link[href="my-style.css"]').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

```
$("link").remove(); // remove all stylesheet links

// now add your new stylesheets
var styleLnk = document.createElement('link');
  styleLnk.setAttribute("type","text/css");
  styleLnk.setAttribute("href", "/myNewStyle.css");
  styleLnk.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");

// add stylesheet to DOM
$("head").append(styleLnk);
```